# Assign students to topics based on rankings

Tags: python, algorithm, traveling-salesman

Suppose I would like to assign 3 students to 3 topics.  The students are allowed to rank each topic from 1 to 3. **Added later: no topic can have more than 2 students.**

The possible assignments of the students are the following permutations (which include the cases where a topic has three students, but ignore them), where each is

(Student 1 topic, Student 2 topic, Student 3 topic)

Note that the three students need not be assigned to different topics.

```
n_topics = 3
n_students = 3


per = [el for el in itertools.product(range(n_topics), repeat=n_students)]
```

We have the student rankings as well

```
rankings = [{0:1, 1:3, 2:2}, #student 1
        {0:3, 1:1, 2:2}, #student 2
        {0:2, 1:1, 2:3}] # ...
```

Hence it is natural to let the ranking be the cost.  So, if a student ranks a topic first and gets assigned to that topic, they pay the minimum cost of 1. If they rank a topic third and get assigned, they pay a cost of 3.

Find the best 3 permutations

```
def get_cost(perm, rankings):
        cost = 0
        for (el, c) in zip(perm, rankings):
                cost += c[el]
        return cost

def get_best_perms(per, rankings):
        perm_cost = {}
        for perm in per:
                perm_cost[perm] = get_cost(perm, rankings)
        return sorted(perm_cost.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0:3]
```

It is best to give the first student the zeroth topic and the second two students the second topic to minimize cost.

```
print(get_best_perms(per, rankings))
#[((0, 1, 1), 3), ((0, 2, 1), 4), ((0, 1, 0), 4)]
```

Really, however, there are 13 students and 7 topics, so 7**13 = 96889010407 permutations (in this case, no topic can have more than 4 students and some of the topics might not be chosen)

Does anyone have any advice (libraries to use, etc) on how to parallelize this code (since each cost can be calculated independently of the others)?  Or how to speed it up in general?

I think this is a Traveling Salesman type problem, but there are so few students and topics I thought it might be possible to try to just try all of the options, but my intuition for the time it might take to do this kind of thing is not very good.

Thank you for your time

***If there is a better place to repost, please let me know!

Comment: On first sight I'd assume your problem probably isn't NP-hard like the travelling salesman. I propose you first identify your problem. If you need help with that, we'll need a more precise description of what makes an optimal solution.

Comment: This looks like a variant of the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

Comment: Added a better description of the problem, thank you for the pointer to the assignment problem.

Comment: I guess there is another constraint to this problem. Because if there is no constraint over assigning topics to students, you can assign each student to the lowest cost topic in linear time. One constraint can be "All topics need to be assigned to some students." In this case, you can use [Hungarian algorithm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html) to match all topics to one student, then use the greedy algorithm.

Comment: What about no topic can have more than n students?

Comment: Do you have to find the very best solution or will "good enough" be enough?

Comment: I think good enough is ok - if it's greedy I guess that's fine.  But it seems like with 100 billion options it should be possible to just check all of them.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54281776/781723, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/42242/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: whoops, removed the cs theory post. had not realized I had hit submit over there, was toying with posting there because there was a close request on this question here

Answer (score 0):

This is a constraint satisfaction problems and quite similar to n-queens problem.We can solve this greedily by applying iterative algorithm.

- Put all the students on best position which minimizes the overall cost(that is at position 0).
- While there are conflicts (a topic gets assigned to more than 4 students),pick one of the conflicted students and move him to a sub-optimal position.
- When there are no conflicts,you get your result.

This algorithm may give the sub-optimal solution but is comparatively faster than backtracking.

Here's a great [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35806/greedy-and-backtracking-solutions-to-an-arrangement-problem-with-constraints) if you want to learn more about the algorithm